# How to change game background image when press button in unity?

Tags: unity

In my game provide two background user can wish to change game background when user press button so how I can do this.

I use a sprite for background.

Comment: What are you using for background in your Game? You can simply find the Texture or Image in Start function and enable/disable that on click.

Comment: I use a sprite for background.

Comment: That's perfect..... You can simply write "(SpriteName).enabled=true or false" on a button click.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways you could do this.

1. Have two SpriteRenderers on screen, each displaying a different sprite.  One enabled, one disabled.   Swap their active states when you want to display the other image.
2. Have one SpriteRenderer on the screen, and swap the active Sprite that it is displaying.   With this option, you would have to set up your Sprites as Resources.

Comment: You can do #2 without setting up the Sprites as resources. Give your swapping script two `public Sprite` member variables, and assign the sprites in the Inspector. That way it has a reference to them immediately, without needing to use `Resources.Load()`